# Direction of Vector3 doesn't affect impact

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine

So I have this code, and I swear, it should work. but it always pushes me towards the wall which im trying to jump off of (walljumping) not away. I've tried changing the direction of the vector, doesn't matter. I've tried using -impact, doesn't matter. It always propels me to the side that im up against. Any ideas guys? I can't figure this out!

```
 void AddImpact(Vector3 dir, float force){
     dir.Normalize();
     // reflect down force on the ground
     impact += dir.normalized * force / mass;
 }
 void Update(){
         if (impact.magnitude > 0.2F) {
             CharCon.Move (impact * Time.deltaTime);
             Debug.Log (impact);
         }
 }
```

.

Comment: When do you call `AddImpact`? And how big is the `Debug.Log` output? Maybe the value is not big enough to compensate other movement.

Comment: @GunnarB. thanks so much, what it was is that my regular movement script was overriding the forces of the wall jump I turned off that movement in the air and now it works great. If you want to re-put your thing as an answer I will mark it correct

Comment: Sure, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

When do you call AddImpact? And how big is the Debug.Log output? Maybe the value is not big enough to **compensate other movement***.

*This was the hint into the right direction, the normal movement overwrote the wall jumping. Turning off other movement when mid air to not override the jump does the trick.